# A confusion in the proof of Stack of records theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

The theorem and its Proof is given below:

> [image]
>
> [image]

But I do not understand in the last line of the proof, why he said that $Z$ is closed and why he is sure that it does not contain $y$ ?

The hint of the book is given below:

> [image]
> [image]

But I am wondering how the above answer proved that $Z$ is compact?
And how he proved that $f$ maps each $V_{t}$ diffeomorphically into $U$ (the third requirement of the question)?

Could anyone help me in answering the previous questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's mostly general topology background knowledge:

$X$ is compact and $Z' = X - \cup_i U''_i$ is a closed subset of $X$, as it's the complement of the open set $\cup_i U''_i$ (a union of open sets is open). So $Z'$ is compact (as a closed subset of a compact space $X$).

$f$ is continuous, so $Z=f[Z']$ is also compact in $Y$ and as $Y$ is Hausdorff, $f[Z']$ is closed, which makes $V$ and $f^{-1}[V]$ open.

Suppose that $y \in Z=f[Z']$. So for some $x \in Z'$ we have $f(x) = y$.
We know that $f^{-1}(y) = \{x_1, \ldots, x_k\}$ so $x = x_i$ for some $i \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$. But then $x \in U''_i$ for that $i$ and so $x \in \cup_i U''_i$ and $x \notin Z'$ by definition of $Z'$. Contradiction so $y \notin f[Z']=Z$.

In essence: we already know all points that map to $y$ and we cut them all away with room to spare to define $Z$. So $Z$ contains no point mapping to $y$ anymore.

Finally $f$ is a local diffeomorphism between $U'_i$ and $V'_i$ and if we restrict both sides to smaller **open** sets so that we still have a bijection between domain and codomain (as we do here), the property of being a local diffeomorphism will be preserved. Check your definition of being a local diffeomorphism, it will be immediate!

Comment: what do you mean by "with room to spare"?

Comment: I think in the forth paragraph it is $f(x) =y$ not $z$..... correct?

Comment: But I think it is unimportant to show that $f[Z]$ is closed ...... correct?

Comment: @hopefully room to spare: neighbourhoods of the $x_i$; the $z$ was a typo. It is important to have the complement of $Z$ open for keeping a diffeomorphism.

Comment: yes complement of $Z$ not of $f[Z]$

Comment: @hopefully yes, I meant the notation as in the proof where $Z$ is the compact image.

Comment: your $Z$ is different from that given in the solution...... so in your notation ..... I think showing that $f[Z]$ is closed is unnecessary for the problem.... correct?

Comment: @hopefully $Z=f[X-\cup_i U’’_i]$ is closed by compactness and this necessary.

Comment: necessary for keeping a diffeomorphism? why?

Comment: @hopefully because we need to restrict to open sets on both sides. The $U_i$ and $V$ must be open.

Answer (score 1):

$Z$ is closed because it is the image of a compact set by a continuous map (actually $Y$ must be Haussdorf for this result). This is a general result of topology.

Comment: Why the set that $f$ acts upon is compact?

Comment: What about the rest of my questions?

Comment: The theorem supposes $X compact$, and $X- \cup U_i "$ is a closed subset of $X$ (assuming the author says "neighborhood" instead of "open neighborhood"), so it is also compact.
About the fact that $Z$ does not contain $y$, it is because all the $x \in X$ that are sent to $y$ by $f$ are not in $X- \cup U_i "$ (since they all are in the $U_i"$.

Comment: And how he proved that $f$ maps each $V_{t}$ diffeomorphically into $U$ (the third requirement of the question)?

Comment: Since $y$ is a regular value, for every $x \in X$ such that $f(x)=y$, the differential of $f$ at $x$ is of maximal rank (this is the definition of a regular value). But $X$ and $Y$ have the same dimension, so these differentials are isomorphism, implying that $f$ is a local diffeomorphism at every $x$ sent to $y$.

Comment: And using that local diffeomorphism implies diffeomorphism if $f$ is 1-1 ...... correct?